# Jquery selector -- how to select the first of specified parents of current element

Tags: jquery

All, I am a newbie of Jquery, I can apply the jquery with the basic usage. But I am not professional of it . I am stucking with this question .Please help me to review it .thanks.

Say you have the source html code like this.

```
...
    <fieldset class="ui-helper-reset">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Select Layout Template:</label>
            <span class="spanSelectedLayout"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ol class="layoutThumbneil ui-selectable">
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">
                    <img class="ui-selectee" src="designer/templates/thumbnails/NullTemplate.PNG" alt="">
                </li>
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected">
                    <img class="ui-selectee" src="designer/templates/thumbnails/2RowsTemplate.PNG" alt="">
                </li>
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">
                    <img class="ui-selectee" src="designer/templates/thumbnails/2ColsTemplate.PNG" alt="">
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </fieldset>
...
```

If the current element is the one of the `li` of the `ol`, and I want to select the `ul` element, let's say that it means the first specified parent of current element. basically , I can make it like below.

```
$(".layoutThumbneil li").bind("click",function(){alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().html());})
```

But this code look like verbose, so my question is Is there any simple way or other selector syntax which I didn't know instead of using `parent()` to make it easily? thanks.

Comment: should You use $(this) or 'current-element'? why dont just directly access ul by $('ul') ? it is same, isn't it?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what do you want ?

Comment: Please see the below answer . `closest` is good . I just want to select the first specified parents of current element recursively. $("ul") mean all the `ul` in the dom . thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone , `closest` is `getting the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree`. it is what i want . `parents()` is getting all the element of selector through its ancestors. not the first. I had upvote you all . but only one right answer . thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector should be `.layoutThumbneil li` and not `.LayoutThumbneil li` given your HTML.

Try:

```
$(".layoutThumbneil li").bind("click", function () {
    console.log($(this).closest("ul").html());
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KkJ4P/)

Comment: Thanks. I had fixed it . :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
$(".layoutThumbneil li").on("click",function() {
     var html = $(this).closest('ul').html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with selectors, but you should give `id` to `ul` elements, if they are important.

change function() { .. } to

```
function(){ alert($(this).parents('ul') .. )}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this (it will select the parent ul element):

```
$(".LayoutThumbneil li").bind("click", function() {
    alert($(this).parents("ul").html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery's [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to go up the tree in conjunction with jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to go back down the tree.

```
$(".layoutThumbneil li").bind("click", function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents('.ui-helper-reset');
  var first_ul = parent.find('> ul');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use closest like this..

```
$(".LayoutThumbneil li").bind("click",function(){
    alert(
        $(this).closest('ol') // this is to check if it has a parent ol
          .closest('ul').html()
    );
})
```